# UML diagram for function calls

Tags: uml, function-calls

Which UML diagram is best suited for depicting function calls? Also are there any diagrams where we can also mention the parameters that we pass to the called functions?

Answer (score 17):

[Sequence diagrams](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/sequenceDiagram.htm) are appropriate to represent function calls, and you can specify the parameters and returned values as well.

Answer (score 10):

[Communication Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_diagram) are also an option and tend to go into more detail with regards to parameters used within function calls.